# Empty value of a search form

Tags: php, html, forms

I want to search in an address book from a page which I am developing. The address book is a content of another page and the url of the address book on this page is http://example.com/start.php. This address book has its own search field, which I will use for my page.
I have written the following search form:

```
<form action="http://example.com/start.php" method="post" target="_blank">
<div>

<input type="hidden" value="adress" name="cmd" /> 
<input id = "adressinput" name="search" type="text" title="Search in the adress book [ctrl-f]" accesskey="f" value="adress book" />
<input id="refresh" title="refreshnow" name="refresh" type="image" src="icons/Downloads/arrow-circle-single.png" class="iconbutton"/>                               

</div>
</form>
```

The problem is that, when I write something in the text box of my form and after that click on the icon refreshnow, the page http://example.com/start.php (the address book) is displayed, but the search field of this page still has an empty value and I don't get any result, of course.

This wasn't my first search form. I have written similar forms and they work, so, I have no idea why it doesn't work.

Answer (score 0):

1. Remove the target attribute from the form, there is absolutely no reason on planet Earth to be using pop-ups any more, ever.

2.) What scripting language are you using? If PHP are you referencing the `$_POST['search']` or did you accidentally reference `$_GET['search']`?

Comment: I am using PHP as a scripting language and you are right I don't need the target attribute. It was only for me to see better what is happening by searching.

Answer (score 0):

This line

```
<input id = "adressinput" name="search" type="text" title="Search in the adress book [ctrl-f]" accesskey="f" value="adress book" />
```

should be

```
<input id="adressinput" name="search" type="text" title="Search in the address book [ctrl-f]" accesskey="f" value="<?php echo $_POST['search']; ?>" />
```

or you could do something a bit more clever

```
if (isset($_POST['search'])) {
    ?>
    <input id="adressinput" name="search" type="text" title="Search in the address book [ctrl-f]" accesskey="f" value="<?php echo $_POST['search']; ?>" />
    <?php
} else {
    ?>
    <input id="adressinput" name="search" type="text" title="Search in the address book [ctrl-f]" accesskey="f" value="adress book" />
    <?php
}
```

It's a bit messy, you could also use a variable in the `value` of the `input` so that the number of lines in your file will be less, e.g.

```
if (isset($_POST['search'])) {
    $value = $_POST['search'];
} else {
    $value = 'adress book'
}

<input id="adressinput" name="search" type="text" title="Search in the address book [ctrl-f]" accesskey="f" value="<?php echo $value; ?>" />
```

Where `$_POST['search']` will contain the value of the search terms entered (once the form is submitted that is.

This is the value you will need to query your database with for search results matching its contents.

Comment: You can't just echo the `$_POST` variable, you need to use `isset()` first. `<?php if (isset($_POST['search'])) {echo $_POST['search'];}?>` though I think your answer may be more on target, the OP wasn't exactly clear from the start.

Comment: @John, not sure what you mean, I'm checking the `POST` variable with `isset` already?

Comment: If you don't check for a variable it'll throw off a minor warning. Sometimes hackers will try to omit a GET/POST variable to see what errors the server will report back when they try to determine a potential attack vector. The only thing your code should report back in an HTTP 4xx error however and log *every* PHP error no matter how insignificant.

Comment: @John and martincarlin87 many thanks for your answers. :) I will try it by myself. Hope it works!

Comment: Unfortunatlly,using POST method didn't change anything at all.